# Error:: QtQuick packages are not installed

Tags: qt, 3d, qnx, qt3d, canvas3d

I am trying to execute the canvas3d project on qnx platform. While execution it throws an error as below

```
qrc:/main.qml:40:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:39:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:38:1: module "QtCanvas3D" is not installed
```

main.qml has imported below

`import QtQuick 2.0
 import QtCanvas3D 1.0
 import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
 import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0`

Can anyone help me to figure out how can I install this missing modules?
I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1(enterprise) licensed version.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error by using env variable QML2_IMPORT_PATH.
But Now I am getting an error `qrc:/main.qml:37:1: module "QtCanvas3D" plugin "qtcanvas3d" not found`

Can some one please let me know what can be done for this?

Comment: Good that you solved your questoin. If you have a new one please ask a new question :) If people start answering your new question with answers here it becomes completely confusing. To me it looks like you didn't install the necessary packages - you should be able to install them via the Qt Maintenance tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-layouts
```

etc.